# Moving catalyst framework project to another server

Tags: perl, admin, catalyst

I had moved my Perl catalyst framework project files from my old server to a new one.
I have moved each and every file but when I take the url its showing up 404 error.
Is there anything else I need to do when the files are moved?
Please let me know as its the 1st time I am doing it.

Thanks
Jitesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the web server, if there is one. Your application was either running as a standalone app with its own PSGI server, or with another PSGI server like Starman, or through an FCGI handler with a web server like Apache, or as CGI. In all cases, you need to move that piece of infrastructure to the new physical server computer.

See [Catalyst::Manual::Deployment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Manual::Deployment) for infos.

I also suggest to look for documentation of your project that any predecessors might have written, or ask your local sysadmin.

Comment: I can see myapp_fastcgi.pl inside script folder. So according to the documentation I tried to run myapp_fastcgi.pl . But it was showing error -- Unable to load the FCGI module, you may need to install it:
Can't locate FCGI.pm in @INC.
Can I know how to install it?

Comment: After installing FASTCGI its showing Class::MOP::load_class is deprecated. Should I upgrade catalyst?

Comment: You should maybe check which version of catalyst you had before and if it was fairly recent just run the makefile.PL which is in the project directory. Install all the dependencies from CPAN.

Comment: Earlier it was 5.7014 and currently it is 5.80033. I tried running Makefile.pl - Output was --
include /home/weaesoca/public_html/application/inc/Module/Install.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
The path 'lib\wealthe.pm' does not exist, or is not a file at /usr/share/perl5/Module/Install/Metadata.pm line 229.

Comment: Is there a Dist::Zilla? That would be easy for all the installations. You can also install cpanminus and just simply copy all the module names in `requires` and `test_requires` from the makefile to a `cpanm Foo::Bar Baz::Quz` kind of call if it doesn't work with the makefile. The makefile should have installed with the plain old CPAN client.

Comment: I have update the catalyst version to 5.9 and installed most of the modules but its still showing up - Class::MOP::load_class is deprecated.