# Move Working Perl Catalyst web app to New server

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a working copy of Perl catalyst web app and I need to move all the files to a new server.
The web app is developed in Catlayst 5.7 and the new server has the catalyst 5.9 in it.
Firstly I created a new catalyst app in the new server and after that I moved the old catalyst files from the other server to the new one inside the newly created app and then I tried to run the myapp_server.pl from scripts folder.
I got a lot of error and was not able to understand the issue.
It will be nice if someone can help me with this issues.
Please check the error:

```
Class::MOP::load_class is deprecated at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Class/MOP.pm line 69.
        Class::MOP::load_class("wealthe::Script::Server") called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 14
        eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 14
        Catalyst::ScriptRunner::run("Catalyst::ScriptRunner", "wealthe", "Server") called at wealthe_server.pl line 8
Class::MOP::load_class is deprecated at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Class/MOP.pm line 69.
        Class::MOP::load_class("wealthe") called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRole.pm line 48
        Catalyst::ScriptRole::_run_application(Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x274dc98)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/Script/Server.pm line 1                                                                             92
        Catalyst::Script::Server::run(Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x274dc98)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 20
        Catalyst::ScriptRunner::run("Catalyst::ScriptRunner", "wealthe", "Server") called at wealthe_server.pl line 8
Class::MOP::load_class is deprecated at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Class/MOP.pm line 69.
        Class::MOP::load_class("Catalyst::Plugin::Crypt::CBC", undef) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst.pm line 2836
        Catalyst::setup_plugins("wealthe", ARRAY(0x2dd09c8)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst.pm line 1118
        Catalyst::setup("wealthe") called at /home/wealth-esolutions/wealthe/script/../lib/wealthe.pm line 66
        require wealthe.pm called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Module/Runtime.pm line 317
        Module::Runtime::require_module("wealthe") called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 180
        Class::Load::try {...} () called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 76
        eval {...} called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 72
        Try::Tiny::try(CODE(0x274d470), Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x274d908)) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 186
        Class::Load::try_load_class("wealthe", undef) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 41
        Class::Load::load_class("wealthe") called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRole.pm line 48
        Catalyst::ScriptRole::_run_application(Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x274dc98)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/Script/Server.pm line 1                                                                             92
        Catalyst::Script::Server::run(Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x274dc98)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 20
        Catalyst::ScriptRunner::run("Catalyst::ScriptRunner", "wealthe", "Server") called at wealthe_server.pl line 8
Class::MOP::is_class_loaded is deprecated at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Class/MOP.pm line 87.
        Class::MOP::is_class_loaded("Catalyst::Stats") called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/Utils.pm line 279
        Catalyst::Utils::ensure_class_loaded("Catalyst::Stats") called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst.pm line 2770
        Catalyst::setup_stats("wealthe", undef) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst.pm line 1121
        Catalyst::setup("wealthe") called at /home/wealth-esolutions/wealthe/script/../lib/wealthe.pm line 66
        require wealthe.pm called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Module/Runtime.pm line 317
        Module::Runtime::require_module("wealthe") called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 180
        Class::Load::try {...} () called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 76
        eval {...} called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 72
        Try::Tiny::try(CODE(0x274d470), Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x274d908)) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 186
        Class::Load::try_load_class("wealthe", undef) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/Class/Load.pm line 41
        Class::Load::load_class("wealthe") called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRole.pm line 48
        Catalyst::ScriptRole::_run_application(Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x274dc98)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/Script/Server.pm line 1                                                                             92
        Catalyst::Script::Server::run(Catalyst::Script::Server=HASH(0x274dc98)) called at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 20
        Catalyst::ScriptRunner::run("Catalyst::ScriptRunner", "wealthe", "Server") called at wealthe_server.pl line 8
Can't call method "read" on an undefined value at /usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/Plugin/ConfigLoader/Multi.pm line 62.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Catalyst/ScriptRunner.pm line 20.
```

Please let me know in detail if someone is aware of the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is the follow-up of [your last question in the perl tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31652260/1331451). If that one helped you to get here, at least mark the answer accepted please. But it's very good you made this a new question. :)

Comment: But no luck doing all this things

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [Catalyst::Upgrading](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst/Upgrading.pod) guide.

Comment: When linking to external resources, it's best to summarize the key points in your answer.